# How to write member initialization list with an object from another struct

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, member-initialization

If I have a binary search tree header file `BST.h` and inside it I have:

```
template <class type>
struct bstNode
{
    type info;
    bstNode * lLink;
    bstNode * rLink;
};
```

And then I have an `AVL.h` header file and I want to use the `bstNode` struct in my `AVL.h` file like this:

```
template<class type>
struct avlNode
{
    bstNode<type> bstN;
    int height;

    avlNode(const type & data, bstNode<type> *ll, bstNode<type> *rl, int h = 0)
    :    //how would the initialization go here?
};
```

My question is how would I initialize the `avlNode` constructor with the initializer list syntax? I'm not sure how to access the members in `bstN`.

I can do it with the traditional definition outside the struct:

```
template<class type>
avlNode<type>::avlNode(const type & data, bstNode<type> *ll, bstNode<type> * rl, int h)
{
    bstN->info = data;
    bstN->lLink = ll;
    bstN->rLink = rl;
    height = h;
}
```

But I would Like to learn the syntax for the member initialization list when it comes to using an object (`bstN`) from another class/struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bstNode` is currently an aggregate, so you may do directly

```
template<class type>
avlNode<type>::avlNode(const type& data, bstNode<type>* ll, bstNode<type> * rl, int h) :
    bstN{data, ll, rl}, height{h}
{
}
```

Providing `bstNode` constructor may be also an option.

Answer (score 3):

You don't access the members directly in the initialization list. That's why you would make a constructor that takes as many arguments as you need and pass values to it in the initialization list.

For example,

```
template <class type>
struct bstNode
{
    type info;
    bstNode * lLink;
    bstNode * rLink;

    bstNode( const type &data, bstNode *left, bstNode *right ) :
        info( data ), bstNode( left ), bstNode( right )
    {
    }
};
```

Then call this constructor in your avlNode.

```
template<class type>
avlNode<type>::avlNode(const type & data, bstNode<type> *ll, bstNode<type> * rl, int h) :
    bstN( data, ll, rl ), height( h )
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define an construct function in bstNode

```
 template <class type>
    struct bstNode
    {
        type info;
        bstNode * lLink;
        bstNode * rLink;
        bstNode(const type & data = type(), bstNode<type> *ll =0, bstNode<type> *rl =0):info(data),llike(ll),rlick(rl){}
    };
template<class type>
struct avlNode
{
    bstNode<type> bstN;
    int height;

    avlNode(const type & data, bstNode<type> *ll, bstNode<type> *rl, int h = 0)
    :    bstN(data,l1,rl),height(h)
};
```